# Editing translation files from backend

Tags: localization

Is there any plugin that allows admin user to edit localization files from backend interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [plugin](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/translate) does what you want. It allows editing the translations for any static text passed trough Crafts translate functions & filters.